# Slim Templating: Is it possible to put two elements on the same line?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, templating, slim-lang

I often want to nest elements, such as the following navigation:

```
ul
  li
    a(href="#") link Name  
  li
    a(href="#") link Name 
  li
    a(href="#") link Name
```

Is is possible to put li and a on the same line? Some syntax like `li > a` would be nice.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

you can do something like this I believe

```
ul
  li: a href="#" Link1
  li: a href="#" Link2
```

See Inline tags: http://rdoc.info/gems/slim/file/README.md#Inline_tags

Comment: I would add this documentation: http://rdoc.info/gems/slim/frames (Ctrl+F "inline tags")